# Stop CRS rule from triggering for a given argument

Tags: mod-security

I am an absolute newcomer to OWASP ModSecurity, so please excuse me if this is a simple question! Currently, for an image upload function, I get a bunch of "warnings" like the following:

> ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter` (?i)\s\S\b' against variable `ARGS:json.ImageBytes' (Value:` data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gv4SUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAvoAAAAAAIAAABtbnRyUkdCI (474171 characters omitted)' ) [file "/etc/modsecurity.d/owasp-crs/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"] [line "139"] [id "941130"] [rev "2"] [msg "XSS Filter - Category 3: Attribute Vector"] [data "Matched Data: ;base64 found within ARGS:json.ImageBytes: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gv4SUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAvoAAAAAAIAAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAH2QADABsAFQAkAB9hY3NwAAA (474141 characters omitted)"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.0.0"] [maturity "1"] [accuracy "8"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-xss"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/XSS"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-8"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-22"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A3"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/IE1"] [tag "CAPEC-242"] [hostname "XX.XXX.X.XX"] [uri "/emps/api/emps/UpdateImage"] [unique_id "160217346360.547876"] [ref "o15,7v29,474271t:utf8toUnicode,t:urlDecodeUni,t:htmlEntityDecode,t:jsDecode,t:cssDecode,t:removeNulls"]

I need to prevent rule 941130 from triggering in the case that the argument (ARGS) is "json.ImageBytes".

I dont want to completely exclude the rule, but i am trying to get ModSecurity to ignore in the case of the specified parameter.

Maybe also - is there a way to do this by the URI ("/emps/api/emps/UpdateImage")?

So far i have tried:

SecRuleUpdateTargetById 941130 !ARGS:json.ImageBytes

but to no avail.

I would be very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the given information, you can create an exclusion rule - just put in in the `REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf`.

The rule like like this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /emps/api/emps/UpdateImage" \
    "id:9000901,\
    phase:1,\
    t:none,\
    nolog,\
    pass,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=941130;ARGS:json.ImageBytes"
```

or something similar.

Comment: thanks! Just one question - what is id: 9000901 in that case?

Comment: When you use SecAction or SecRule in ModSecurity's config, you MUST to add a unique identifier for each rule (or action). The only exception is if the rule is chained: in that case the whole chained rule must have a unique identifier. There is a recommendation of allocation for these id's, see this page: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#id. As you wrote you use CRS, which can uses 900,000–999,999, but we use a plus digit for exceptions, from 9,000,000 to up.